# Temporary authentication via query string

Tags: authentication, yii

My goal is to be able to generate a special URL that would allow someone to view a normally "protected" view temporarily. In fact, if they leave the page, any temporary authentication that was granted should be taken away.

Basically the problem is that I have content on my website that I NORMALLY want to be protected by requiring a login. However, I'd like to be able to give temporary access to a specific asset and not require a login.

Should I somehow use a URL with a query string that automatically authenticates the user? Or should I instead generate a separate page with that asset that does not require authentication at all?

edit: I forgot to mention that the generated link should be accessable for more than one person. In other words, it can't limit by the number of times accessed, but rather a time period or until we manually force it to expire.

Comment: show what you have done to achieve this? We are here to solve your problem but not to do your work.

Comment: Are you talking about an asset like a `PDF file`, or are you talking about a view as `render()`'ed by Yii?

Comment: The problem I have is that my current solution is wrong... But I'm using php and jquery to input a un/pw into the login form and submit. This of course gives the fake user access to everything anyone else has access to.

It's not a matter of a simple code fix. I'm not asking for someone to do the work for me. Instead I'm asking for direction in achieving my goal.

Comment: Ivo, it's for both actually. It should first be for a rendered view that also contains PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a database table like `tokens`, where you store unique access tokens which are valid only for 1 single request. In your action, this token could be a URL parameter. If no token is present in URL or if the token was not found in the DB table, access is denied. If a token was found, you delete it from DB and perform the action.

Now whenever you want to give someone this kind of one-off access, you create such a token and store it to DB. The token could be a random MD5 hash, that you generate e.g. through `md5(mt_rand().mt_rand())`. Then you can create a URL with that token as parameter and hand it out to the user.

You can also enhance the system and add an expiration time to your `tokens` table. Then you'd only grant access if the expiration time is in the future.

Comment: This looks promising. I'd probably have to go the route of an expiration time though as we will share this "token" access with multiple users. Also, the access is for a view that also contains assets like pdfs the user should be able to download as well.

Answer (score 0):

vyce: "*It should first be for a rendered view that also contains PDF files.*"

If you have PDF files (or any other files) accessible under your webroot, anyone can access them at any time. So even if you will only serve a view to your user once, he/she could still get to the PDF file if they have kept the PDF's URL. The user can also share that URL with others.

This problem can be resolved by:

1. - Storing the PDF file under the document root (or in another location that is made inaccessible with `.htaccess`)
2. - Once you have determined that your user is allowed a one-time peek at the PDF, you serve it as described [here](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/pdf-cookies-headers-rewrites.html)

Comment: The problem is that the PDF files as well as the rendered view should NORMALLY be secured. We're intentionally making an exception for a short period of time.

Comment: Exactly. So the best place for the PDF'is is too have them '*off the grid*' altogether. And then serve them if and when the user qualifies.